# Is there any data on the latency of an AVX2 gather instruction?

Tags: performance, x86, latency, micro-optimization, avx2

Is there any data on AVX2 gather latency?

(for instance a _mm256_i32gather_ps instruction accessing a single cache line)

Comment: Just one empirical data point - I ran a quick benchmark for a gathered load recently and throughput was pretty bad - I was loading a split vector, so the first half of the vector came from one cache line and the second half from another - it seemed to take quite a few cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page gives latency data for all intrinsics:

[Intel Intrinsics Guide](http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/)

The latency for _mm256_i32gather_ps is 6.

Comment: NB: those are the minimum latencies.

Comment: No way, the minimum latency is something like 17 cycles for the smallest gathers (2 elements) and 22 cycles for the large ones (8 elements like the DD forms), at least if you measure in the usual way from address input to result.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this really depends on the hardware. If you look at Agner Fog's [instruction tables](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf), you'll see that there are no latencies listed for Zen1 and Zen2, but have reciprocal throughputs of 13-20 and 9-16 for VGATHERDPS. For Intel processors we have:

```
                     xmm                 ymm
Processor    throughput latency  throughput latency
-------------------------------------------------------
Haswell          9                    12
Broadwell        6                     7
Skylake          4         12          5       13
SkylakeX         4         12          5       13
Coffee Lake      4         12          5       13
```

Also, [Intel's site](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide) no longer lists the throughput/latencies of of the gather instructions for AVX2, but there are some for AVX512.

Comment: Also worth checking https://uops.info/ - they publish the microbenchmark instruction sequences they used, and automate the tests.

Comment: @PeterCordes Wow. Thanks for that amazing resource. Almost too much information in those tables.

Comment: I always turn off the "documentation" and "IACA" columns; I don't care about them being sometimes wrong, I just want real measurements.  That cuts down clutter enough to compare data from a couple microarchitectures.